# Independence of dice rolls

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose that a fair dice is rolled and that the number $x$ appears. Let
$E_1$ be the event that the number $x$ is even, $E_2$ be the event that the
number $x$ is greater than or equal to $3$, $E_3$ be the event that the
number $x$ is a $4,5$ or $6$.
Are the events $E_1$ and $E_2$ independent? Are the events $E_1$ and $E_3$
independent?

I would say events $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent because

$\mathbb{P}(E1 \cap E2) = \mathbb{P}(E1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(E2) \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\{4,6\}) = \mathbb{P}(E1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(E2) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{6}$

Comment: Well, you still haven't considered the $E_1, E_3$ case.

Comment: This would be also dependent because $1/2 \neq 1/2 \cdot 1/2$?

Comment: How many numbers from $1$ to $6$ are both even and at least $3$? Also, how many are both even and equal to $4$, $5$, or $6$?

Answer (score 1):

You initially got it backwards. Because, for example,

$$\mathbb{P}(E1 \cap E2) \neq \mathbb{P}(E1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(E2),$$

they're *dependent*, or *not independent*.

But, if the joint probability equals the product of the individual probabilities, then the events are independent.

Comment: yes thats what ive meant but is my way for the solution correct? I am still not complete safe with the definitions of probability

Comment: You did the work, but reached the wrong conclusion.

Comment: If you change the line above your equation to: "I would say the Events are all *dependent* because ..." then you're good.

Comment: The reasoning is now correct, but I believe the work is wrong, since $P(E_1\cap E_2)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: But then its is $\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$ what would mean they are independent

Comment: I think you've sorted it out. You have the correct answer. I didn't actually follow through on the math but saw what you wrote initially, which on the face of it was backwards. But I do think you have it now. If they're equal, then then should be independent.

Comment: yes but why is $E_1$ and $E_2$ independent but $E_1$ and $E_3$ not instinctively?

Comment: Frankly, this was part of how I wrote my initial answer, which wasn't correct. It's *not* instinctive. I initially thought -- incorrectly -- that because there was overlap in the sets, the probabilities were dependent. Not so. You have to look at the definition and calculate.

Comment: @bonapartenent Explaining the intuition behind this will just summarize the computations, so the best I can say is that $E_2$ looks at the numbers from $3$ to $6$, which is half even numbers, half odd numbers, while $E_3$ looks at the numbers from $4$ to $6$, which contains more even than odd numbers. In the whole space, from $1$ to $6$, you get half of each.